# Getting an error when trying to register EC2 with ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-codestar

Working on AWS and at a loss with this...

I am trying to register an EC2 instance to an ECS Cluster, the EC2 instance was launched as part of Codestar project.

Steps I have followed as per AWS documentation:

- Go to ECS
- Access Cluster
- Click on Register External Instances
- Click to next page
- Copy the Curl command for Linux to register the EC2 to the Cluster.

When I input the Curl command into the Linux CLI it runs, however stalls on this line:
Trying to wait for ECS agent to start ...

Soon after I recieve an error that states:
Timed out waiting for ECS Agent to start.
Logs show:

> ===================================================
>
> level=error time=2022-06-14T18:19:25Z msg="Unable to register as a
> container instance with ECS: InvalidParameterException: The identity
> document and identity document signature were not valid."
> module=client.go level=error time=2022-06-14T18:19:25Z msg="Error
> registering container instance" error="InvalidParameterException: The
> identity document and identity document signature were not valid."
>
> ===================================================l

Can anyone help identify what the issue is?

TIA!

Comment: Does your EC2 instance have network access to the AWS ECS service? It sounds like it is in a private subnet without an ECS VPC Endpoint or a route to a NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input - Mark B

I had a Eureka moment!

Well it dosent resolve the error I posted, but found another way around this.
Basically I do not need to use or register the EC2 instance created by codestar.

I was able to update the codepipeline 'Deploy' stage to deploy to ECS (instances) and with a few tweaks to the codestar IAM role it is working!

So can consider the matter closed.

Many thanks